# Duck translation

Tags: translation

Dictionary translates 'duck' as 'anatra' and 'anitra'. I googled for difference explanation and found in [this topic](https://www.duolingo.com/comment/419887/The-duck) that Italians use 'papera'. So, how should I call duck in Italian?

Comment: We also have the masculine form *papero*. By the way, Disney ducks are considered *paperi* in Italian. Donald Duck is Paperino, Scrooge McDuck is Paperon de' Paperoni and so on.

Comment: @DaG: And a "rubber duck" is also "una papera di gomma" or "una paperella di gomma"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Anatra* refers to the wild animal while *papera* refers to the same animal considered as a pet.

From [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/anatre-oche-cigni_%28Enciclopedia-dei-ragazzi%29/):

> Il germano reale (Anas platyrhynchos) e l'oca selvatica (Anser anser)
> sono allevati da almeno 2.500 anni e hanno dato origine
> rispettivamente all'*anatra domestica*, detta anche *papera*, e all'oca
> domestica.

[Anitra](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/anitra_%28Enciclopedia-Dantesca%29/) is an old fashioned word for anatra.

So you can use both (even if I prefer anatra for *duck*)

Comment: Google translation: 'The royal jellyfish and the wild goose have been bred for at least 2,500 years and have given birth to domestic ducks, also known as papera, and domestic goats.' I like this version =)

Comment: Seems ok, give or take a few random animals. :) Do you need a less fanciful translation?

Comment: @LSerni: Do you feel this is all that's wrong with that translation by Google?

Comment: @DaG, I did not pay attention to the "translation" at all. My mistake.